# select multiple where in a condition (nested condition) on mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to select multi-column and condition in a condition (nested condition) like a one below if it is written in a programming language:

```
(bulan_pembayaran == 7 && semester_payment == 1) && (bulan_pembayaran == 6 && semester_payment == 4)
```

How to make the above command for SQL query?

Comment: *but not work* is not an error description. Please describe what it means. Also add some sample data and the expected result

Comment: I think it should be `(bulan_pembayaran = 7 and semester_payment = 1)   or 
(bulan_pembayaran = 6 and semester_payment = 4);` ? Because a column can not have 2 values at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you just use boolean operators just as you would in a programming language.  mysql uses `or`/`||` and `and`/`&&` interchangeably, but because `||` is a concatenation operator in other flavors of sql, it can be good to stick to `or`/`and`:

```
(bulan_pembayaran = 7 and semester_payment = 1) or (bulan_pembayaran = 6 and semester_payment = 4)
```

(The parentheses are only needed for clarity here; `and` is higher precedence than `or`, so without them it would produce the same result.)

But in this specific case, you can use mysql's support for list values and the `in` operator; this is especially helpful when there are more than a couple cases being checked:

```
(bulan_pembayaran, semester_payment) in ((7,1),(6,4))
```